# Tensorflow (1.13.1) Exception when import: DLL load failed (Windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed Python 3.7.3 on my Windows 10 machine. 
Afterwards I downloaded with the tensorflow module:
`pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

On the computer is Visual Studio 2019 installed with additional MSVC v141 (VS 2017) and MSVC v140 (VS 2015).

When I run `import tensorflow as tf` in python, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tested some solutions from other answers, but nothing has solved my problem. Does anyone have an idea?

---

Edit:
The reason was that my CPU has no AVX support. Now it works.

Comment: Your `tensorflow` is 64-bit. Is your Python installation also 64-bit? The bitness has to match, and that is the kind of error you get when it doesn't.

Comment: I agree with @BoarGules. Seems like an issue with your version

Comment: @BoarGules Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: In that case, it is likely that the `tensorflow` DLL is trying to load another DLL that it can't find. If there is a chain of dynamic loads, Windows will very often complain about the first one in the chain, and not tell you where the real problem is.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you, then what are the next steps for me to try out? reinstall visual studio?

Comment: Look up tensorflow's dependencies in its documentation and import them manually one by one.

Comment: @Green678 some recent comments on similar issues suggest few solutions [Win10: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794#issuecomment-482915167) maybe it is worth to give it a try? Did you tested the configuration of `CUDA 10.0, cuDNN v7.5.0.56, Python 3.6.7 and tensorflow 1.13.1`?

Comment: Thank for your answers, but nothing worked so far. Steps I tried: 1) removed all installed python packages 2) deinstalled Visual Studio 2019 and installed Visual Studio 2017 3) deinstalled `Python, CUDA and cuDNN` and installed `CUDA 10.0, cuDNN v7.5.0.56, Python 3.6.7 and tensorflow 1.13.1`

Comment: @BoarGules sorry to bother you, but can you give me a link to the dependencies?

Comment: If I install tensorflow on a 64-bit system it lists as dependencies (and installs, or checks for the presence of) the following:  absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.7.1 gast-0.2.2 grpcio-1.20.1 h5py-2.9.0 keras-applications-1.0.7 keras-preprocessing-1.0.9 markdown-3.1 protobuf-3.7.1 tensorboard-1.13.1 tensorflow-1.13.1 tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.15.2 wheel-0.33.4 numpy>=1.13.3 six>=1.10.0 mock>=2.0.0 setuptools pbr>=0.11

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks, every module gets loaded except `tensorflow_estimator` and `tensorflow`. The error code for `tensorflow_estimator` is added to the main contribution. Is there another hint in this error message?

Comment: And what happens if you do `pip install tensorflow-estimator` at the Windows console command prompt? It should give you 6 *Requirement already satisfied* messages.

Comment: @BoarGules it says that `tensorflow_estimator`, `absl-py>=0.1.6`, `mock>=2.0.0`, `numpy>=1.13.3`, `six>=1.10.0` are already satisfied. But this are only 4 or 5 Requirements?

Comment: I also got the requirement `pbr`. At this point I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @BoarGules ok thank you for your efforts. Maybe someone else has another idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TensorFlow release binaries version 1.6 and higher are prebuilt with AVX instruction sets.**

Therefore on any CPU that does not have these instruction sets, either CPU or GPU version of TF will fail to load.
Apparently, your CPU model does not support AVX instruction sets. You can still use TensorFlow with the alternatives given below:

- Try Google Colab to use TensorFlow.
  The easiest way to use TF will be to switch to google colab.You get pre-installed latest stable TF version. Also you can use pip install to install any other preferred TF version.
  It has an added advantage since you can you easily switch to different hardware accelerators (cpu, gpu, tpu) as per the task.
  All you need is a good internet connection and you are all set.
- Try to build TF from sources by changing CPU optimization flags.